# C++ Polymorphism Employee Project

Tags: c++

For class I have to adapt a program I wrote last week for polymorphism. Last week it used a specific set of information for the employees but now I have to make it work with polymorphism as well as read/write data from a file, I am completely lost with what I am supposed to be doing, If someone could even point me in the right direction it would be so much help. I can post my current .h and .cpp file for a look at what I have as well as the instructions of what I am supposed to be doing.

**.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Employee {
    private:
        int employeeNumber; // Employee's employee number
        string employeeName; //Employee's name
        string streetAddress; //Employee's street address
        string phoneNumber; //Employee's phone number
        double hourlyWage; //Employee's hourly wage
        double hoursWorked; //Employee's hours worked
        double netPay; //Net pay
        double grossPay; //Gross pay
    public:

Employee();
Employee(int, string, string, string, double, double);



    int getEmployeeNumber();
    void setEmployeeNumber(int);

    string getEmployeeName();
    void setEmployeeName(string);

    string getStreetAddress();
    void setStreetAddress(string);

    string getPhoneNumber();
    void setPhoneNumber(string);

    double getHourlyWage();
    void setHourlyWage(double);

    double getHoursWorked();
    void setHoursWorked(double);



double calcPay()
{
    const int OVER = 40;
    double federal = 0.20;
    double state = 0.075;
    double timeHalf = 1.5;
    double grossPay;
    double netPay;
    if (getHoursWorked() < OVER)
    {
        grossPay = getHoursWorked() * getHourlyWage();
        netPay = grossPay - (grossPay * federal) - (grossPay * state);
    }

    if (getHoursWorked() >= OVER)
    {
        grossPay = getHoursWorked() * ((getHourlyWage() * timeHalf));
        netPay = grossPay - (grossPay * federal) - (grossPay * state);

    }
    return netPay;
}




};
```

**.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "Employee.h"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

Employee::Employee()
{
    employeeNumber = 0; // Employee's employee number
    employeeName = ""; //Employee's name
    streetAddress = ""; //Employee's street address
    phoneNumber = ""; //Employee's phone number
    hourlyWage = 0; //Employee's hourly wage
    hoursWorked = 0;
    grossPay = 0;
    netPay = 0;
}


Employee::Employee(int empNum, string empName, string streetAddress,
string phoneNumber, double hourlyWage, double hoursWorked)
{

    employeeNumber = empNum;
    employeeName = empName;
    this->streetAddress = streetAddress;
    this->phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this->hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    this->hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    grossPay = 0;
    netPay = 0;
}

int Employee::getEmployeeNumber()
{
    return employeeNumber;
}

void Employee::setEmployeeNumber(int empNum)
{
    employeeNumber = empNum;
}

string Employee::getEmployeeName()
{
    return employeeName;
}

void Employee::setEmployeeName(string empName)
{
    employeeName = empName;
}


string Employee::getStreetAddress()
{
    return streetAddress;
}

void Employee::setStreetAddress(string strtAddrs)
{
    streetAddress = strtAddrs;
}

string Employee::getPhoneNumber()
{
    return phoneNumber;
}

void Employee::setPhoneNumber(string phnNum)
{
    phoneNumber = phnNum;
}

double Employee::getHourlyWage()
{
    return hourlyWage;
}

void Employee::setHourlyWage(double hrWage)
{
    hourlyWage = hrWage;
}

double Employee::getHoursWorked()
{
    return hoursWorked;
}

void Employee::setHoursWorked(double hrWorked)
{
    hoursWorked = hrWorked;
}

void printCheck(Employee ee)
{
cout << "\n\n--------------------- Fluff Shuffle Electronics -------------------------------- \n";
cout << " Pay to the order of " << ee.getEmployeeName() << "...........................$" << ee.calcPay();
cout << "\n\n United Bank of Eastern Orem \n";
cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n";
cout << " Hours Worked: " << ee.getHoursWorked();
cout << "\n Hourly Wage: " << ee.getHourlyWage();
cout << endl << endl;

}//End of function

void read(ifstream &in)
{

    Employee employees[10];
    int counter = 0;
    while (in.read((char *)&employees[counter++], sizeof(Employee)))
    for (int i = 0; i<counter; i++)
        {
            printCheck(employees[i]);
        }
    in.close();
}

void write(ofstream &out)
{
    Instantiate your employees here first, then call their functions.
    Employee joe(37, "Joe Brown", "123 Main St.", "123-6788", 10.00,
45.00);
    printCheck(joe);
    Employee sam(21, "Sam Jones", "45 East State", "661-9000", 12.00,
30.00);
    printCheck(sam);
Employee mary(15, "Mary Smith", "12 High Street", "401-8900", 15.00, 40.00);
printCheck(mary);
out.write((char *)(&joe), sizeof(Employee));
out.write((char *)(&sam), sizeof(Employee));
out.write((char *)(&mary), sizeof(Employee));
out.close();
}

//Main function
int main()
{
    int choice;
    string filename;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\nThis program has two options:\n";
        cout << "1 - Create a data file, or\n";
        cout << "2 - Read data from a file and print paychecks\n";
        cout << "\n Press any other key to quit..........\n";
        cout << "Please enter <1> to create a file or <2> to print
        checks: ";
        cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter the file name: ";
        cin >> filename;
        ofstream out(filename);
        out.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
        write(out);
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        cout << "Enter the file name: ";
        cin >> filename;
        ifstream in(filename);
        in.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
        read(in);

    }
    else break;
    //Calls function to displays information


}
}//End of main
```

[These are the instructions for the project](https://pastebin.com/30r6tEsn).

This is the diagram it refers to

[image: diagram]

Comment: You need to speak to your lecturer or tutor to get an understanding of polymorphism. You're paying a lot of money for your education. Ask questions in class to ensure that money is worthwhile.

Comment: You have the UML diagram there. You have made the base class, so now create the subclasses. The required functions are all there spelled out for you. You should approach your lecturer wrt what you are stuck on. I don't think anyone will type of a lengthy explanation here, when such explanations exist in books, in on-line tutorials and hopefully in a one on one with your tutor. btw both links point to the same thing.

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant for people to do your homework for you.  If you are stuck on something in particular, isolate the problem to a minimum example and then ask about only that.  But don't just post a bunch of code and instructions and expect someone to fix it for you, or explain what it is and how it works. That is what your instructor is for.

Comment: A tip on your code comments: `int employeeNumber; // Employee's employee number` That comment contributes nothing. The variable name is good, so the comment is not needed. (If a variable name is bad, first try fix the variable name before adding comments,) If you delete the redundant comments, then the important comments stand out more.

Answer (score 1):

To start: create two classes derived from Employee:

```
class HourlyEmployee: public Employee
{
};

class SalariedEmployee: public Employee
{
}
```

and move members related to Hourly working from Employee to HourlyEmployee, then add members related to Salary to SalariedEmployee (WeeklySalary).

This way (removing attributes related to hourly working) you make Employee class more general that can be a base for other kind of employees to (SalariedEmployee).

When you derive HourlyEmployee or SalariedEmployee from Employee, you mean they are kind of Employee, so members that Employee has, they will inherit automatically.